# Constant polling, or Java RMI?

Tags: java, udp, rmi

If I were to send a packet from one computer to another computer, directly connected via one ethernet cable, is it quicker to constantly poll on the receiving computer with UDP, or use Java RMI for the sender to "give" the packet to the receiving computer?

I was unaware if there was any performance variation?

Comment: Quicker how? for whom? What do you mean by 'constantly poll'? The normal technique for receiving UDP datagrams is a separate thread that blocks in a `receive()` method, not 'constantly polling'.

Comment: I was going to write a single-threaded Java framework between two computers to try and benchmark how many "messages" I can send between the two computers. I wasn't sure if having a while(true) loop, constantly checking for new UDP messages would be the fastest way. I presume that is all your receive() does?

Comment: It's not 'my receive()', it's DatagramSocket's receive(), and it does what it says in the Javadoc. If you have additional constraints such as single-threading they should be stated in the question, but then you are loading the dice, because RMI is not single threaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally faster to do UDP, as there is no additional acknowledgement overhead on the transmission, as there is no need to bother with receipt acknowledgements.

With TCP, there is an acknowledgement transmitted back to the source of the data.  Full duplex communications can make the transmission of this acknowledgement occur without disrupting the incoming data stream; however, you do have to wait *some* amount of time for that acknowledgement to return the the sender, and that sender to process it.

While both computers are assumed to be fast enough to handle the data stream processing, in the real world computers might find themselves doing multiple tasks which could interrupt ability to handle network traffic at line speeds.  In such a scenario, if the transmitting computer cannot receive the acknowledgements quickly enough (or the receiving computer cannot transmit them fast enough) then you may exhaust your window of unacknowledged packets, which would result in the transmitting computer halting transmission until it determined that either what was transmitted would need re-transmission or was received.

But UDP is no bed of roses, as it's solution to not acknowledging receipt is to allow any packet to disappear without notice at any time.  As such, it is ideal for data that doesn't need to be transmitted completely (live voice, if it's dropped it is more important to start with the "now" packet than collect them all), or for data where the retransmission is managed by more efficient application-specific algorithms.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wasn't really asking TCP vs UDP, it was the way in which I am alerted I have new data. My worry was that constantly polling isn't the most efficient way of receiving the packets as soon as possible- or is this the best method to receive packets as soon as possible?

Comment: Well Java RMI is typically implemented with TCP, so RMI is RMI `on top of` TCP, so it is TCP with an additional protocol on top.  With UDP you will have to build the protocol on top, and for _specific scenarios_ you _can_ beat TCP easily, but for generalized scenarios, you will re-implement TCP.

Comment: Hi Edwin, not sure if you can see my comment below my original question. I want to test how many messages I can receive on a computer (similar to the Java Disruptor pattern if you have heard of it) this is where my question originated from. See: http://www.slideshare.net/JAX_London/java-core-understanding-the-disruptor-a-beginners-guide-to-hardcore-concurrency-trisha-gee-mike-barker

Comment: I'm very familiar with the Disruptor pattern, http://stackoverflow.com/q/10020101/302139 .  That said, the disruptor pattern is for messages after they have been read out of the network infrastructure, for low network latency, you need to consider the _network's_ behaviour, not the post-network handling code.